# Adjusting yscale in terminal panel in survival ctree plot

Tags: r, plot, party, survival

I am using `ctree()` in package `party`/`partykit` to plot a survival tree of a survival model.

Overall survival is good, 95% survival at worst, so I would like to change the `yscale` to `c(0.9, 1)` so that the panels are useful on the final plot.

I need to adjust the `yscale` arguments in the terminal panels of the survival plots but this throws up an error and does not seem to be possible.

Is this possible in `ctree()` or should I use another method?

I have added arguments for `yscale` to the `terminal_panel` function but this thorws up an error

```
"Error in survfitKM(X, newY, casewt, ...) : 
  unused argument (yscale = c(0.9, 1))"

    plot(taperfit.ct, terminal_panel = node_surv(taperfit.ct, yscale = c(0.9, 1)))
```

I expected this to change the scale to zoom in on the KM plots with y axis scale form 90% survival to 100% survival, but this did not happen.

Comment: I have been working on this and I have located the code in the node_surv function which controls the KM plot panel but I cannot seem to alter the code to adjust the output. I have used the following: fixInNamespace("node_surv", "party") to view and edit the code temporarily but this makes no difference. I have also tried using: trace(node_surv, edit=TRUE) but this throws the error:"unable to find an environment containing class “grapcon_generator”" any ideas?

Comment: I have also tried using: "plot(taperfit.ct, terminal_panel = node_surv, tp_args= list(yscale = c(0.9,1)))" but this throws error: "Error in survfitKM(X, newY, casewt, ...) :   unused argument (yscale = c(0.9, 1))"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far the `node_surv()` function did not have a `yscale` argument and hence when you provided it, it got passed on to the wrong function yielding an error. However, I just added it to the `partykit` repository on R-Forge. Thus, if you check out and build `partykit` from there your code

```
plot(taperfit.ct, terminal_panel = node_surv(taperfit.ct, yscale = c(0.9, 1)))
```

or for short

```
plot(taperfit.ct, tp_args = list(yscale = c(0.9, 1)))
```

should work.

You can also manually work around the issue if you're using the old `party` implementation (or have troubles with building `partykit`).

```
taperplot <- node_surv(taperfit.ct, yscale = c(0.9, 1))
fix(taperplot) ## go to line 11 and change the definition of yscale
plot(taperfit.ct, terminal_panel = taperplot)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will transfer ot Party kit and give this a go.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I have been very slow, sorry. I have used partykit with the arguments listed above (1- terminal panel, 2- tp_args) and the plot still doesn't change. Are there any other ways to get this to work?

Comment: Did you use the latest version of `partykit` from R-Forge. Unfortunately, the package currently does not build automatically, so that you have to check it out and build by hand. Or alternatively, you do the manual workaround I mentioned.

Comment: Hi, sorry I had not got the latest version, I will try this and or work around.